# How to force pathauto to bypass common word removal based on content type?

Tags: 8, path-aliases

If one set up a url pattern for nodes of certain type to `node/[node:title]` and then try to create a node with title `this is my title` the generated pattern is `node/my-title`. This is because pathauto removes common words by default.

I found that some of the value processing is happening at `cleanString` inside `AliasCleaner.php` class. This can be changed via pathauto configuration at `admin/config/search/path/settings`. However, changing the setting is global and I need don't intend on removing this default behavior globally.

Is it possible to hook into the `cleanString` process and alter it only for a specific content type?

Comment: The pathauto configuration has a list of words it will automatically remove. If you remove them from the list, it won’t remove the words anymore.

Comment: I don't want to change the global settings. Is there a way to hook into this behavior and change it based on some rules i.e. content type?